# Easy way to install Python and PyQT

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a long distance friend who has written a little Python script for me to try out.  It has a nice UI as well.  Problem is I am not a coder.  After several days and attempts and reading material that is now over my head I must ask how to do this.

1. Install Python 2.7  I have done this.
2. Script error message says I need to install PyQT.
3. But before I can install PyQT I must install PIP?
4. And Before I can install PIP I must install 'MAKE'?
5. And before I can install MAKE I must install C/C++?

Really?  All this must be installed?  I am at a loss.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Ooops, that would be on Windows 7

Comment: You can get a Windows installer for PyQt4 [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).